# Is it possible to search the Module for orphaned objects?

Tags: object, module, ibm-doors, orphaned-objects

I was wondering if it is at all possible to run a DXL script to find any orphaned objects within the module. 
When im working on a project with 400-500 + objects it can be hard to search through the entire list to find orphaned objects just floating around. 
I am very new to this DOORS program and DXL as well and thought it would be best to ask here.

Comment: any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming here that: you're looking for objects with no outlinks; you've got the module open.

```
Filter f_noOutlinks = hasNoLinks(linkFilterOutgoing, "*")
set f_noOutlinks
filtering on
```

I suspect you also might just want to show the requirements, not any other objects. Different organizations handle that differently, so I'll assume you've got an attribute called "Object Type" that sets off requirements, so add that in:

```
Filter f_noOutlinks = hasNoLinks(linkFilterOutgoing, "*")
Filter f_req = attribute "Object Type" == "Requirement"
Filter f = f_noOutlinks && f_req
set f
filtering on
```

The result here should be that you'll show only requirements without a parent in the module window. There is more info about filters in Chapter 25: Display Control > Filters in the DXL Reference Manual ([for version 9.6 DOORS](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYQBZ_9.6.0/com.ibm.doors.requirements.doc/topics/dxl_reference_manual.pdf)).